# Linq c# use between on time span

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have two field in data base named "StartTime" and "EndTime"

I have saved a record as

```
StartTime           EndTime
05:00:00.0000000    06:00:00.0000000
```

I want to display an error message if another record is inserted at the same or between 05:00:00.0000000 to 06:00:00.0000000

This means no matter what the start and end times are it should not occur between 05 to 06.

```
04 to 06 - Show error
04:30 to 06 - Show error
05:00 to 07 - Show error
```

How I achieve this using linq?

This is my current attempt, which does not generate the proper results:

```
string _timepicker_start = collection["timepicker_start"];
string _timepicker_end = collection["timepicker_end"];
TimeSpan _end = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(_timepicker_end.Split(':')[0])
    ,  Convert.ToInt16(_timepicker_end.Split(':')[1]), 00);
TimeSpan _start = new TimeSpan(Convert.ToInt16(_timepicker_start.Split(':')[0])
    , Convert.ToInt16(_timepicker_start.Split(':')[1]), 00);

var _schedule = _db.Classes
                 .Where(c => c.StartTime <= _start && c.EndTime >= _end)
                .FirstOrDefault(); 

if (_schedule != null)
{
    // Show message already have record.. 
}
```

It does not work properly please suggest me.

Comment: As a side note...you can use `.Any()` instead of `.FirstOrDefault()` if you never use the result....`_db.Classes.Any(c => c.EndTime >= _start && c.StartTime <= _end)`

Comment: @Servy Thank you for helping to clarify.  I didn't quite get what the output was supposed to be when I answered, and removed my post.

Answer (score 3):

You want `c => c.EndTime > _start && c.StartTime < _end` in your `Where`.

(Add equality if you don't want the items to be able to "touch" at either end.)

This assumes you're validating `StartTime` <= `EndTime` for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to stack over flow:

I have got my solution as:

```
            var _schedule = _db.Classes
             .Where(c => (c.StartTime >= _start || c.StartTime <_end)&& c.EndTime > _end)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Thanks for quick response and help !!!

Comment: That's not right.  You should use Rawling's answer.  Your addition actually prevents it from matching certain items that it really should match.